# How to remove dots in Tableau filled map by zipcode

Tags: tableau-api

When I generate filled map by zip code, I get these tiny dots. Besides cranking the opacity to 100% to mask them, is there a way to remove them from and only have a filled map?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you changed the mark type from Automatic to Filled Map? See the combo box on the Marks Card.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the dots are caused by one of two scenarios:
1. Some zip code are too small and its only plotted as a location instead of a shaded region
2. Some buildings are large enough to have their own zip codes

The only way to remove the dots is to remove (filter) those entries.